# wpf DataGrid SelectedItem get NullReferenceException after binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

**Finally**

> I discover property "Item" maybe reuse of SelectedItem = {Binding
>   Item}, so it always get exception.

I had a DataGrid, include expander.

**Edit** *When I want to use SelectedItem, I get "NullReferenceException".*

When I want to do something, like UnSelectAll or Collection.Remove SelectedItem, I get "NullReferenceException".

**Example is called UnSelectAll stacktrace**

```
---------------------------
   於 MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid(Object item)

   於 MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid()

   於 MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.get_IsDBNullValidForUpdate()

   於 MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.get_IsDBNullValidForUpdate()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertProposedValue(Object value)

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateOverride()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Update()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.ProcessDirty()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Object value)

   於 System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)

   於 System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)

   於 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdatePublicSelectionProperties()

   於 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()

   於 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UnselectAllImpl()

   於 System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.UnselectAllCells()

   於 SList.Expander_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 於 D:\SList.xaml.cs: 行 123, System.NullReferenceException: 並未將物件參考設定為物件的執行個體。

   於 MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid(Object item)

   於 MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid()

   於 MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.get_IsDBNullValidForUpdate()

   於 MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.get_IsDBNullValidForUpdate()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertProposedValue(Object value)

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateOverride()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Update()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.ProcessDirty()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty()

   於 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Object value)

   於 System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)

   於 System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)

   於 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdatePublicSelectionProperties()

   於 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()

   於 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UnselectAllImpl()

   於 System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.UnselectAllCells()

   於 SList.Expander_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 於 D:\SList.xaml.cs: 行 123
---------------------------
```

But SelectedIndex work well.

I don't know what happening, but I need binding SelectedItem.

please help!

**My ViewModel**

```
public class TestVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _index;
    public int Index
    {
        get
        {
            return _index;
        }
        set
        {
            _index = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Index");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private User _item;
    public User Item
    {
        get
        {
            return _item;
        }
        set
        {
            _item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<User> _collection;
    public ObservableCollection<User> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return _collection;
        }
        private set
        {
            _collection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }

    ListCollectionView _groupView;
    public ListCollectionView GroupView
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupView;
        }
        private set
        {
            _groupView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("GroupView");
        }
    }

    public TestVM()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe1", Age = 10, group = "Group 1" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe2", Age = 20, group = "Group 1" });

        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 30, group = "Group 2" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe1", Age = 40, group = "Group 2" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe2", Age = 50, group = "Group 2" });

        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe3", Age = 60, group = "Group 3" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe4", Age = 70, group = "Group 3" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe5", Age = 80, group = "Group 3" });

        GroupView = new ListCollectionView(Collection);
        GroupView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("group"));
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int Age { set; get; }

    public string group { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Index, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: I have copy your code, and it runs and execute with no errors. then i have add in TestVm property for selected item like. private User _selectedUser;

        public User SelectedUser
        {
            get { return _selectedUser; }
            set
            {
                _selectedUser = value;
                MessageBox.Show(SelectedUser.Name);
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedUser));
            }
        } and in MainWindos changed SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}", and it works. Selected item is shown in MessageBox just to show purpos

Comment: Something is work of SelectedItem, you're right. But you can try call UnSelectAll(). Or, Remove SelectedItem from Collection. I get exception when mode is TwoWay. But OneWay is work.

Comment: if you have no item selected pops a exception, try to change `int Index` to `int? Index` (also change your field) should fix it

Comment: @CelsoLivero But SelectedIndex is work well, what need to change it?

Comment: The answer here did it for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245601/wpf-why-get-nullreferenceexception-when-binding-selecteditem-edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add Command to test that removale of Selected item and it still Works.
Here is what i have done.

Made Class DelegateCommand

```
 public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            }
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

In TestVm i have added property for ICommand

```
public ICommand RemoveSelectedItem { get; private set; }
```

in constructor ov TestVm inicialize that command.

```
RemoveSelectedItem = new DelegateCommand(OnRemoveSelecteditem);
```

and OnRemoveSelecteditem Method is just this.

```
private void OnRemoveSelecteditem(object commandParam)
        {
            Collection.Remove((User)commandParam);
        }
```

Inside MainWindow i have added Button just to call that command like this:

```
<Button Content="RemoveSelectedItem"
                Command="{Binding RemoveSelectedItem}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg,Path=SelectedItem}"
                Height="25"
                Width="150"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

and it still works :) You can select item and click on that Button will get it remove.

Comment: Your answer is wonderful for remove SelectedItem using MVVM, but it not hit this question. I still to call dg.UnSelectAll method,and so on, maybe I can try it like your answer. If no others answer, I will choice this! Thank you very much!

Comment: oh, i see. you will use Code behinde to call dg, and to perform some operation on it. Well, i try always to use MVVM, with no code behinde. If you wan't, you can check some templates for dataGrid, and inject Button in each row for Delete. And there will CommandParameter be just {Binding}

Comment: Maybe my question is what is happen get exception when call UnSelectAll from set SelectedItem binding mode to TwoWay?

Comment: Finally, I discover property "Item" maybe reuse of `SelectedItem = {Binding Item}`, so it always get exception. But your answer let me see clearly, thx.

Comment: Great, im glad you could fix that problem :)

Comment: But I search again, no any ver naming "Item", this name is C# or WPF `Reserved word`?

Answer (score 0):

Error in ==> SelectedIndex="{Binding Index}"
changed with ==>SelectedIndex="{Binding Index,Mode=TwoWay}"

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupView}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Index,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" 
          CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          FontWeight="Bold"
          RowHeaderWidth="0"
          GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <!-- Remove the focus indication for the selected cell -->
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sign" MinWidth="100" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="LightGray"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Fill="DimGray"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" Header="No." Binding="{Binding Age}" Foreground="Peru"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="200" Width="Auto" Header="Command Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Foreground="LimeGreen"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best 2 answers I found were the following:

1) The answer here [wpf why get "NullReferenceException" when binding SelectedItem [Edit]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245601/wpf-why-get-nullreferenceexception-when-binding-selecteditem-edit) which is to use one-way binding
2) If you need to maintain binding to your ViewModel, use SelectedIndex instead (and then simply grab the selected value via ElementAt method on your ObservableCollection

Number 2 ended up being the solution I went with.